# get all documents from previous month in couchbase server 5.1

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to get all documents from previous month in `couchbase` server `5.1.1`.

I have a field `dateCreation` in timestamp

my query will be launched every month(M) at 15 day to retreive M-1 documents.

i use N1QL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON bucket(dateCreation);
SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE dateCreation >= DATE_ADD_STR(CLOCK_STR(), -1, 'month');
```

You can change CLOCK_STR() with constant or change as query parameter and supply the value.

Checkout DATE functions https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html

Comment: i want to get only docs from previous month, for example i am in month 8, i want to get all docs from month 7, your query does not

Comment: and i have to manage month like january, because i need to get all docs from last year (i.e december)

Comment: You need to adjust first argument of DATE_ADD_STR().  SELECT DATE_ADD_STR(CLOCK_STR(), -1, 'month') AS a, DATE_ADD_STR("2018-01-22T09:42:26.447-07:00",-1, 'month') AS b; returns  {
            "a": "2018-07-22T09:45:38.141-07:00",
            "b": "2017-12-22T09:42:26.447-07:00"
        }

Answer (score 1):

To supplement vsr's answer, since you want all documents from the previous calendar month, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM bucket 
WHERE 
  dateCreation >= SUBSTR(DATE_ADD_STR(CLOCK_STR(), -1, 'month'),0,8) || "01" 
and 
  dateCreation < SUBSTR(CLOCK_STR(),0,8) || "01";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can also help:

```
SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE DATE_DIFF_STR(NOW_UTC(), dateCreation, 'month') <= 1
```